# Google Drive API | PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api

We are facing some problems on searching query.
When we searching by `imageMediaMetadata` field with conditions as `imageMediaMetadata has {key=, value=}` or even with simple `imageMediaMetadata.time` , as mentioned in documentation - error will be occur.

Fields are selected : `files(imageMediaMetadata, name, id)`

With simple `mimeType` search - it's OK.

[image: Search by MIME-TYPE]

But, when we will try to do another request, with imageMediaMetadata fields(keys) - it will fail.

[image: Fail on imageMediaMetadata search]

We have tried requests with property keys and accessing to object with dot - nothing work. All scopes that needed - are granted.

**UPD 1**

Even if width parameter was passed as integer - it still does not work.
We are trying to get photos, where `imageMediaMetadata.time > t`, where t is user-defined time

**Solution**

As per [DalmTo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42087676/4713486) answer, there is only [allowed list of fields](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/search-parameters)(primary), that can be used for search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant search on every field there are specific ones you can search on they are

> Field Value Type  Operators   Description
>  **title**   string  contains1, =,
>   !=    Title of the file.
>  **fullText** string  contains2   Full text of the
>   file including title, description, content, and indexable text.
>   **mimeType**  string  contains, =, != MIME type of the file.
>   **modifiedDate**  date3   <=, <, =, !=, >, >= Date of the last modification
>   of the file.
>  **lastViewedByMeDate**   date3   <=, <, =, !=, >, >= Date
>   that the user last viewed a file.
>  **trashed** boolean =, !=   Whether
>   the file is in the trash or not.
>  **starred**  boolean =, !=   Whether the
>   file is starred or not.
>  **parents**   collection  in  Whether the parents
>   collection contains the specified ID.
>  **owners**  collection  in  Users
>   who own the file.
>  **writers** collection  in  Users who have permission
>   to modify the file.
>  **readers**   collection  in  Users who have
>   permission to read the file.
>  **sharedWithMe** boolean =, !=   Files that
>   have been shared with the authorized user.
>   **properties**    collection  has Custom file properties.

A full list of valid search parameters can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/search-parameters) really though they would have fixed this in V3

An idea would be to update the files and add [custom properties](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/properties) that you could then search on but this may or may not work for you.

Comment: It was as example. What about time field?

Comment: It doesn't work. Same problem with invalid parameter

Comment: Actually, we had a lot of tries with adding custom properties, but still same error.  We was reading v2 and v3 fields. I got the point why. 
Maybe, in cause of search can be performed by primary fields

Comment: I remember being bit by this a few years ago now.   I tried everything even json to format the other fields.